# wordpress restore in new hosting

Tags: wordpress, restore

I've got a wordpress backup to restore a website in a new hosting. I have zero experience in wordpress and I only know is a php application that uses myqsl database. My questions are.. can I restore the database if it has different database data (database name, user and password) than the original one? or do I need to delete the default database created in the wordpress installation? If the website used themes or plugins or something else.. do they need to be installed before the restore process, in order to the website to work? (I unzipped the backup file and noticed an 'Avada' folder in the themes zip, and many subfolders in the plugins zip.. one of them the updraftplus that I guessed was used to create the backup file)
Thanks

Comment: This site is for questions about programming

Answer (score 0):

for anyone with these questions, the database is overwritten and the themes and plugins are loaded with the restore process (by the updraftplus plugin)